# MySQL - appropriate application of VIEWS or FOREIGN KEYS

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Suppose I have a table that acts as an inventory of my house - `inventory_items` if you will. `inventory_items` contains everything I own, but only the most general information (i.e fields that will apply to everything I own, like a name, purchase date).

I then wish to have a separate table for `electronics_data` which is an inventory item, but has special information to store (lets say serial_number, wattage) and another for `furniture_data` which contains furniture specific information (number_of_legs, material).

In all instances, items in `electronics_data` will have a matching item in `inventory_items` linked by an id field. The same is true of `furniture_data`.

If I now wish to show a list of my inventory items, but include specific information from the child tables, logically I think to load the `inventory_data`, find out what type of item this is, and load the right information from the right table. I can think of two better ways:

1) Create a foreign key relationship between `inventory_items` and `electronics_data` - thus loading all items will get me all of my child data too. **But, not all items in `inventory_items` will have a matching item in `electronics_data` so does this mean a foreign key can't work?**

2) Create a view which loads the extra tables if a matching item exists in them, and load the view in my application. **If I have lots of different 'types' of data, will this make my view unnecessarily slow (checking everything) and actually defeat the object of the view in the first place?**

These are general questions - particularly 2) I would imagine is very data dependent.

Thanks!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with database administration, this is a design question.

Comment: @Shadow - noted. Wording adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Follow the EAV tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

well it will make your life easier if you could join the tables when extracting data. There are a lot of ways to join tables, in your case if all your tables have an I.D column then you could use an 'Equijoin' This is how you could do so

```
SELECT inventory_items.name, electronics_data.wattage, furniture_data.material 
FROM inventory_items, electronics_data, furniture_data
WHERE inventory_items.i.d=electronics_data.i.d=furniture_data.id;
```

so with a join like this you can add as many columns as you wish but make sure to highlight the table they are from and in the 'WHERE' clause show where they are equal otherwise it wont return any data

Comment: It is better to use an explicit join syntax, so you can easily distinguish between the join criteria and the filter criteria. Also, if the OP joins multiple child tables the way you suggested, then the result will be empty.

Comment: That is not how you may use = in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

1) Foreign keys will work, since the specialised tables are the child tables, so you need to make sure that each record in the child table has a corresponding record in the overall inventory_items table. The reverse is not necessarily true.

2) The view can `left join` the child tables on the inventory_items table. If the fields used in the join are indexed in all tables, then the operation is not that resource intensive. The biggest catch could be how you build the view, if you have lots of specialised child tables. But this is probably a wider application design question anyway (if you are looking at your electronic devices, then you probably do not want to see the fields from the furniture items table - in these specialised views I would use `inner join`, not `left join`).

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an fairly detailed response to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904925/3658753), even how to define the views you mention. Note that the code shown in the view definition is for illustration only. It will not show the most efficient way to write it. Better ways should be fairly straight-forward, however.

A word about view performance. Take a view that joins very large tables in such a way that the query

```
select * from <view>
```

takes a long time, say 30 minutes. The query

```
select * from <view> where <criteria>
```

could take fractions of a second. In most modern DBMSs, the `where` criteria is merged with the existing query in the view definition to execute the query. It does not execute the view definition and *then* do the filtering. So test view performance with actual queries not "data dump" queries.